# how do i get filter column with different format?

Tags: c#, winforms, format, repository, devexpress

how do i get the format time in my gridview column to set it on my repository ?
the date in database was using `date time` which return an output of `8/1/2016 12:00:00 AM`
and i set in a gridcolumn with this method

```
    private void arrange()
    {

        gridView1.Columns["date"].VisibleIndex = 1;
        gridView1.Columns["date"].DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.DateTime;
        gridView1.Columns["date"].DisplayFormat.FormatString = "dd MMM yyyy";
        gridView1.Columns["date"].format.FormatString = "dd MMM yyyy";

        gridView1.Columns["date"].Width = 150;
    }
```

the display on the gridcolumn of date is

[image]

the problem is when i using repository item on filter row it still getting the date format from database which is `8/1/2016 12:00:00 AM`. the image was like this

[image]

the code to add item into repository combobox was

```
    RepositoryItemComboBox repositoryItemComboBox2 = new RepositoryItemComboBox();

    private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView view = sender as GridView;
        for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            if (gridView1.GetDataRow(i) == null)
            {
                break;
            }
        string txt = gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["date"].ToString();
        if (!repositoryItemComboBox2.Items.Contains(txt))
            {                    
                repositoryItemComboBox2.Items.Add(txt);
            }
        }

        if (e.Column.FieldName == "date" && view.IsFilterRow(e.RowHandle))
            { e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemComboBox2;

            repositoryItemComboBox2.Sorted = true;

            }
     }
```

iam thinking , how to resolve this is:

1. how to i really converting the column of date, not by display text
2. formating the column of date
3. formating the repository itemcombobox
4. using the original format, but on repository itembox change the display text same as how i did on column date
5. your suggestion

n.b: iam using devexpress

Answer (score 0):

I share my sample via DropBox to you in recent Question.Check it. Here my code.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Date",typeof(DateTime));

        List<DateTime> str = new List<DateTime>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            if (i < 20)
                dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString());
            else
                dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString());
        }

        gcDate.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        gcDate.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.DateTime;

        repositoryItemComboBox1.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        repositoryItemComboBox1.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.DateTime;

        repositoryItemComboBox1.EditFormat.FormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        repositoryItemComboBox1.EditFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.DateTime;

        gridControl1.DataSource = dt;

        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
            repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(item["Date"]).ToShortDateString());
        }
    }

private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView view = sender as GridView;

        if (e.Column.FieldName == "Date" && view.IsFilterRow(e.RowHandle))
        {
            e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemComboBox1;
        }
    }
```

[image][image]

Comment: how can i set  `dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString());`
when iam using query ? my code was http://pastebin.com/UCFC8k4J